# Pandas read_excel new string type error when passing "string" using converters parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

So I am just playing around with Pandas new string type, as of 1.0.0 Jan 2020.

```
import pandas as pd
test_series = pd.Series(["text", "text2", "text3"], dtype="string")  
print(f"1 -\n{test_series.dtype}\n ")  # series

test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[("text", "test2")], columns=['col_1', 'col_2'], dtype="string")  
print(f"2 -\n{test_df.dtypes}\n ")  # df change all cols

test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[("text")], columns=['col_1'])  
test_df = test_df.astype(dtype={"col_1": "string"})
print(f"3 -\n{test_df.dtypes}\n ")  # single col

test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[("text", "test2")], columns=['col_1', 'col_2'])  
test_df = test_df.astype(dtype={"col_1": "string", "col_2": "str"})
print(f"4 -\n{test_df.dtypes}\n ")  # multi col mixed types

test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[("text", "test2")], columns=['col_1', 'col_2'])  
test_df = test_df.astype(dtype={"col_1": "string"})  # change only one col
print(f"5 -\n{test_df.dtypes}\n ")
```

output

```
1 -
string

2 -
col_1    string
col_2    string
dtype: object

3 -
col_1    string
dtype: object

4 -
col_1    string
col_2    object
dtype: object

5 -
col_1    string
col_2    object
dtype: object
```

Now all the above work which is great. A good start

Now try read_excel with this basic dataset

[image]

```
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx_input_path, 'Sheet1',  engine="openpyxl")  
df = df.astype(dtype={"col_1": "string", "col_2": "string"})
print(f"6 -\n{df.dtypes}\n ")

df = pd.read_excel(xlsx_input_path, 'Sheet1', dtype={"col_1": "string", "col_2": str}, engine="openpyxl")
print(f"7 -\n{df.dtypes}\n ")

df = pd.read_excel(xlsx_input_path, 'Sheet1', converters={"col_1": str, "col_2": str}, engine="openpyxl")
print(f"8 -\n{df.dtypes}\n ")
```

output

```
6 -
col_1    string
col_2    string
dtype: object

7 -
col_1    string
col_2    object
dtype: object

8 -
col_1    object
col_2    object
dtype: object
```

Again as expected. But note `'str'` returns `object` but `'string'` returns a string.

*My question* is how do I pass the new string type via the converters perimeter? neither `"string"` or `string` work. Yes `str` works but gives type `object` not the new type `string`.

```
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx_input_path, 'Sheet1', converters={"col_1": "string", "col_2": "string"}, engine="openpyxl")
print(f"9 -\n{df.dtypes}\n ")  # TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

df = pd.read_excel(xlsx_input_path, 'Sheet1', converters={"col_1": string, "col_2": string}, engine="openpyxl")
print(f"9 -\n{df.dtypes}\n ")  # NameError: name 'string' is not defined
```

Comment: `str` and `'str'` were commonly used for object before the new `pd.StringDtype` so likely to not break tons of code those still point to object, while `'string'`, which was never used, now coverts to the new dtype.

Comment: As for the converters, it doesn't work because it doesn't make sense. converters convert the **values** and there is no 'string' dtype for values. Whether the column is `object` or `pd.StringDtype`, non-missing values are always the same type `<class 'str'>`. What's different is the dtype of the **`Series`**, not the values. That is a `dtype` property and should be set with the `dtype` argument, not `converters`